# JavaFX transform question mark table view to known type

Tags: java, generics, javafx, tableview

I'm having problems to insert elements to my TableView.

I obtained the tableview's reference casting it from Node. The problem is I'm getting an error when inserting elements to the table.

`The method add(capture#2-of ?) in the type List<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments`

```
TableView<?> table = (TableView<?>)mainPane.getChildren().stream().filter(c -> c instanceof TableView<?>).findFirst().get();

ControlTimePickerController ctpc = new ControlTimePickerController();

if (ctpc.exitedWithButton()) {
    ControlSchedule cSch = ctpc.getSelectedControlSchedule();

    //I'M GETTING THE ERROR HERE
    table.getItems().add(cSch);
}
```

Comment: This example is not complete. What is the return type of `mainPane.getChildren()`? Please post a minimal, reproducible sample first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another type parameter indicating that `ControlSchedule` is indeed a type that can be added to the `items` list or use the raw type. The latter approach has a similar effect to using `TableView<Object>` in this case. However using the raw type is discouraged; in this case you've already thrown the type safety out of the window anyways.

Here I'd recommend using

```
TableView<? super ControlSchedule> table = (TableView<? super ControlSchedule>)mainPane.getChildren().stream().filter(c -> c instanceof TableView<?>).findFirst().get();
```

But you need to be 100% sure this cast won't break anything. There are plenty of objects used to set up a `TableView` that could result in an exception, if the type of the `TableView` does not in fact match the type parameter used in the declaration of the `table` variable above.

I don't recommend using this kind of code anyways. A better alternative would be using a suitable datastructure to store the `TableView`(s). This would allow you to avoid this kind of cast by allowing the compiler to do checks.